# How to prevent hydrogen embrittlement in SmCo magnet?

Tags: physical-chemistry, materials, magnetism

We have a measuring apparatus that incorporates a [samarium-cobalt (SmCo) magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samarium%E2%80%93cobalt_magnet). Normally this is exposed to various gases under test. However, a problem has arisen with hydrogen, namely the magnet shattered.

I am assuming it is hydrogen embrittlement in magnets according to [Shin-Etsu Chemical Co., Ltd. — Characteristics of Hydrogen Absorption Characteristics of Hydrogen Absorption on RE Magnets on RE Magnets (PDF)](https://www.intemag.com/images/uploads/Hydrogen_Absorption_Neo_SmCo_Magnet_Material.pdf).

How to prevent it? The only thing I can think of is some kind of metal plating or encapsulation. Of the two, the former is preferable.

Has anyone come across this problem and knows the solution?

We will be doing tests in Hydrogen of both plated and unplated magnets. The one that shattered was not plated.

Comment: Related: [nature.com Novel Methods for Prevention of Hydrogen Embrittlement in Iron](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-17263-8) and [wikipedia.org Hydrogen_embrittlement#Prevention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_embrittlement#Prevention)

Comment: Related: [engineering.stackexchange.com how-can-we-prevent-detect-hydrogen-embrittlement](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87/how-can-we-prevent-detect-hydrogen-embrittlement)

Comment: I think embrittlement of RE magnets is something different from H embrittlement of steels. For example , austenitic stainless can absorb significant amounts of H and do not embrittle.

Comment: @black you'll still get the corrosion even if there is no carbon to react with. Very expensive corrosion.

Comment: Carbon does not react for embrittlement . Carbon reaction is High Temperature Hydrogen Attack.

Answer (score 3):

### Low-tech >> Hi tech

How about **cling film**? Hydrogen absolutely loves to adsorb and react with noble-ish metals and other d-orbital protruding heavies. Deny them the surface.

Wrap it in plastic. It won't solve anything long term, and it won't gain you any credits with the high brow community, but I bet it'll turn your problem into a nuisance.

Comment: If you want to be more scientific, look up the hydrogen diffusivity in various polymers (before still using cling film).

Comment: @Karl Oh, I know. My chemical plant produces some 2000 m3/h by electrolysis. OPs biggest problem is that his compound looks very tempting for hydrogen to dissociate on. Limiting access to that should help by magnitude or two. But hydrogen penetrates everything in the end.

Comment: OK, it is not hydrogen gas per se, but an embedded hydrogen atom. The latter chemically behaves as an mono-atomic hydrogen radical (where .H <-> H+ + e-). It (namely, .H) will, and per a source does, convert PbS, for example, to Pb and H2S. So, think of .H as operationally a (H+, e-) pair. Your suggested method implies less contact than, for example, a high pressure N2O treatment or soaking in a solvent with a large amount of dissolved N2O. As such, I would expect your process to be much less effective.

Comment: @AJKOER It might be less effective. Also, it is done by the time you call the first guys over to your desk to brainstorm the idea for how to do a gas coating in situ. And it could be effective *enough*.

Comment: Yes, possibly effective on H2 gas!  The latter could be formed from .H + .H = H2 (g). However, that also implies that the .H has already been self-removed (aka, dissipated with time) with an implied marginal improvement, per your suggested process, of precisely zilch. My comment also suggests importantly, if the degree of metal degradation does not improve with time, there is but little hope for a solution.

Comment: There appears to be a lack of understanding on what is occurring. I quote a source "The cathodic reaction produces Hchemisorbed by picking up an electron that released in the anodic reaction (H+ + e = Hchemisorbed ) in Al corrosion in HCl. In such acidic solutions, the Hchemisorbed on the metal surface reacts by combining with other adsorbed Hchemisorbed to form H2 gas molecule, which bubbles from the metal surface. A very small amount of the uncombined Hchemisorbed will remain; however, this amount does not affect ...“ Reference link: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5458939/ .

Answer (score 0):

Try exposing the magnet to N2O either as a gas or dissolved, given its highly soluble in select solvents, especially alcohol.

Logic:

> $ { H˙ + N2O -> OH˙+ N2 }$

Source: See ["Reaction of the hydrogen atom with nitrous oxide in aqueous solution – pulse radiolysis and theoretical study](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2017/ra/c6ra27793d). To quote:

> ...reaction of the H˙ atom with nitrous oxide (N2O) producing N2 and ˙OH in aqueous solution. The H˙ atom attacks the oxygen atom in the N2O molecule resulting in the formation of the [H–ONN]‡ transition state and its decomposition into ˙OH and N2.

The reaction requires energy so UV light may assist. See also [this dated work](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2935493) and as a cautionary note, this work ["The Explosion of Nitrous Oxide--Hydrogen Mixtures"](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01179a036) noting, in general, a potential explosion issue, albeit here, the amount of hydrogen is expected to be low.

Also, considering adding a hydroxyl radical scavenger as per this article ["Sugars as hydroxyl radical scavengers: proof-of-concept by studying the fate of sucralose in Arabidopsis"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25891826/) to address possible metal corrosion.

I expect it to be, at least, an interesting experiment.

[EDIT] More insights from this [2008 doctoral thesis](http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=16827&context=rtd) "Alkaline dissolution of aluminum: surface chemistry and subsurface interfacial phenomena" by Saikat Adhikari, as an example:

> Hydrogen embrittlement, a process in which brittlement and subsequent cracking of metals is caused by ingress of atomic hydrogen into the metal, is also sometimes thought of as a type of stress corrosion cracking. Due to the detrimental effects of such corrosion processes, it is important to have a fundamental understanding of associated alkaline or acidic dissolution mechanisms.

And also:

> Apart from activation of the surface, dissolution of aluminum in alkaline solutions at open-circuit also leads extremely high rates of H-absorption into the metal, [9-14] and also formation of nanoscale voids or hydrogen bubbles [15, 16] near the aluminum surface.

This depiction of hydrogen embrittlement leaves me a little more hopeful on a possible solution, but the alluded to formation also of nano-scale voids (and unspecified possible subsequent pervasiveness when H is removed) could suggest a more unrecoverable condition.

Comment: The question is how easily N2O gets to atomic hydrogen ( or alternative reactive hydrogen forms ) within the alloy.

Comment: The question is there any treatment possible to address the atomic hydrogen? My suggestion is to try safe non-toxic laughing gas based on the suggestive chemistry. Experimentation with various means of possible application may prove somewhat successful (or not).  To be honest, I have not rule out, in my expectations, even if the extraction is successful, whether the brittleness is eliminated or even may worst. Trying may suggest other paths or provide a definitive answer (including none).

Comment: See 'my Hchemisorbed' provided comment above for a better understanding on what is occurring,

Comment: My note was about the thought the atomic H (or similarly reactive bound H) would eventually occur in the close to surface bulk alloy volume, where N2O would not reach because of its size and limited metal diffusibility.

Comment: My understanding is that the process is largely a surface phenomenon. Interestingly, one can crack a glass surface starting with a long scratch. Do you agree that cling film has no impact on surface imbues H atoms?